# Piping into printf

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

In Terminal, I'm trying to replace **MY_SUBJECT** and **BODY_OF_EMAIL** from the command below:

```
printf "From: Sender Name <sender@domain.com>\nTo: recipient@domain.com\nSubject: MY_SUBJECT\n\nBODY_OF_EMAIL\n" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -F "Sender Name" -f "sender@domain.com" "recipient@domain.com"
```

with the piping of

```
ls *
```

I just can't figure out how to do it, any kind soul to help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

It was as simple as replacing both words with `$(ls *)`

So final command is:

```
printf "From: Sender Name <sender@domain.com>\nTo: recipient@domain.com\nSubject: $(ls *)\n\n$(ls *)\n" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -F "Sender Name" -f "sender@domain.com" "recipient@domain.com"
```

Comment: You can use `\`ls *\`` or `$(ls *)`